# How to get wget only save file if its complete

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, wget

I downloading files using wget like this

```
wget http://www.example.com/mysql.zip -O mysql.zip
```

Then i have do stuff with that file.

But sometimes if there is error in url or somewhere then corrupted file `mysql.zip`

is placed in there and my script don't download the file as its already there and script fails.

Is there any way if `mysql.zip` is only placed if file download is complete.

There are two cases when that can happen

1. Url does not exist
2. User manually cancels the download

IN both above cases i don't want the file to be there

Comment: Download to a temporary file and only mv to the final location if `wget` completes succesfully.

Comment: @EtanReisner i am doing that in shell script , how can check if wget downloaded successfuly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if wget http://www.example.com/mysql.zip -O mysql.zip
then
    # Do something with file
else
    rm mysql.zip
fi
```

Comment: it can be done a lot more easier with a logical operator like @Denio Mariz does ;) But great answer anyways

Answer (score 6):

`wget http://www.example.com/mysql.zip -O mysql.zip || rm -f mysql.zip`