# wget: delete incomplete files

Tags: bash, wget

I'm currently using a bash script to download several images using wget.

Unfortunately the server I am downloading from is less than reliable and therefore sometimes when I'm downloading a file, the server will disconnect and the script will move onto the next file, leaving the previous one incomplete.

In order to remedy this I've tried to add a second line after the script fetches all incomplete files using:

```
wget -c myurl.com/image{1..3}.png
```

This seems to work as wget goes back and completes download of the files, but the problem then comes from this: ImageMagick which I use to stich the images in a pdf, claims there are errors with the headers of the images.

My thought of what to with deleting the incomplete files is:

```
wget myurl.com/image{1..3}.png
wget -rmincompletefiles
wget -N myurl.com/image{1..3}.png
convert *.png mypdf.pdf
```

So the question is, what can I use in place of `-rmincompletefiles` that actually exists, or is there a better I should be approaching this issue?

Comment: I don't think I understand how mirroring would help me accomplish what it is I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made surprising discovery when attempting to implement [tvm's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31214922/3147475).

It turns out, and this something I didn't realize, that when you run `wget -N`, wget actually checks file sizes and verifies they are the same. If they are not, the files are deleted and then downloaded again.

So cool tip if you're having the same issue I am!

Comment: `wget -N` checks the timestamp on the server. The timestamp is the LAST thing that wget sets, after the file is fully downloaded, which means that any partially downloaded file is almost guaranteed to have a different timestamp. The problem is, `wget -N` will NOT redownload the file, because it will almost assuredly see an earlier timestamp on the server, and conclude that the local file is newer. You'll get an error which looks like this: `File ‘somefile.mp3’ not modified on server. Omitting download.` wget -N may have worked for you if the server didn't return a timestamp, which happens.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31214181/2859270) to work for my use case.

From the answer:

```
wget http://www.example.com/mysql.zip -O mysql.zip || rm -f mysql.zip
```

This way, the file will only be deleted if an error or cancellation occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would try hard to download the files with `wget` (you can specify extra parameters like larger `--timeout` to give the server some extra time). `wget` assumes certain things about the partial downloads and even with proper resume, they can sometimes end up mangled (unless you check their eg. MD5 sums by other means).

Since you are using `convert` and `bash`, there will be most likely another tool available from the Imagemagick package - namely `identify`.

While certain features are surely poorly documented, it has one awesome functionality - it can identify broken (or partially downloaded images).

```
➜  ~  identify b.jpg; echo $?
identify.im6: Invalid JPEG file structure: ...
1
```

It will return exit status 1 if you call it on the inconsistent image. You can remove these inconsistent images using simple loop such as:

```
for i in *.png;
   do identify "$i" || rm -f "$i";
done
```

Then I would try to download again the files that are broken.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that identify is actually accepting my partially downloaded images. I'm not sure why, but it does and then attempts to pass them to convert which returns `convert: corrupt image 2.png @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3958.`